# Adding an already deleted Service Provider in WSO2

Tags: wso2-identity-server

This problem is described in this JIRA: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2089.
The fix has been provided for Release [5.0.0 Alpha](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY/fixforversion/11437) but in v5.0.0 I am facing the same issue.

What is the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This patch is already in the WSO2IS 5.0.0.
could you please provide any error log you are getting. And its better if you send the steps to reproduce this

Comment: steps and the error message are same as given in the JIRA.

Comment: Can you try it in a fresh pack. It works fine. if your environment is change please let me know

Comment: I actually ended up removing and re-installing WSO IS. But even in the new install I faced this issue.

Comment: Its strange, do you have any configuration changes in your server